# Spring Boot Application on Kubernetes How to use external message.properties file for supporting i18n and l10n?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, internationalization

We have a spring boot application that is deployed to Kubernetes. We are adding i18n capabilities to this application and want to place the messages.properties file outside the application jar/war. I have been able to do that in spring boot. How will this work when I deploy it on Kubernetes? Do I need to use the configmaps? Following is the code snippet

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    //Path to the messages.properties files
    messageSource.setBasenames("file:/messages/messages", "classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(60);
    return messageSource;
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do this with a configmap. It is much the same as accessing an external application.properties file. First you can [create a ConfigMap directly from the file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files) or create a [ConfigMap representing the file](https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/secrets-treasurehunt/blob/master/treasurehunt/config.yaml):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: treasurehunt-config
  namespace: default
data:
  application.properties: |
    treasurehunt.max.attempts=5
```

Then in your kubernetes Deployment you create a [Volume for the ConfigMap](https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/secrets-treasurehunt/blob/master/treasurehunt/deployment.yaml#L39) and [mount that into the Pod under the directory you use for the external configuration](https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/secrets-treasurehunt/blob/master/treasurehunt/deployment.yaml#L35):

```
          volumeMounts:
          - name: application-config
            mountPath: "/config"
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: application-config
        configMap:
          name: treasurehunt-config
          items:
          - key: application.properties
            path: application.properties
```

These snippets come from an [example of mounting a Volume from ConfigMap](https://dzone.com/articles/hunting-treasure-with-kubernetes-configmaps-and-se) for an application.properties file so they use the spring boot [default external properties file path](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) of `/config`. You can [set that in the yaml for the mount](https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/secrets-treasurehunt/blob/master/treasurehunt/deployment.yaml#L37) so you could mount the file to use the same relative path that you are already using when running outside of kubernetes.

Comment: Ryan, if I have messages.properties for 10 languages should I create config map for all of them? For Eg: One for messages.properties, one for messages_fr_FR.properties and so on. And what changes will have to be made in the application code? How will my application understand that it has to read from configMap file or it is agnostic to that? I am new to Kubernetes and could not find info on this

Comment: You can include multiple files in the same configmap and they'll all be mounted in the directory. To add more files to the example above you'd put them at the same level of yaml indentation as the application.properties. The application can just access the mounted directory like any other directory. It doesn't need to know how the directory got there.

Comment: Spring-boot happily snarfs the application.properties file in its current working directory at start. What is the right mountPath or other K8S magic incantation to get that behavior - should the mountPath be just "/" instead of "/config"?

Comment: According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files it should be /config